# How to avoid updating update_at flag while updating associated model in active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, associations

My association to models as follows

**People model**

> belongs_to :category 
>     has_one :account, :through => :category

**category model**

> belongs_to :account
>  has_many
>   :bookings

**account model**

> has_many :categories

**Level model**

> accepts_nested_attributes :peoples

I wrote

> @level.update_attributes(params[:level])

in Level controller.

Here when I update the level model then it also updates the updated_at flag in account_model. I want to avoid the update happen in account model i.e, avoid setting up updated_at flag in account model. how can I avoid this?

Comment: A minor quibble, but it's easier on the eyes to name your class "Person". That way the pluralized version ("people") makes sense, whereas `"people".pluralize == "peoples"`, which is just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to do something like this:

```
Account.record_timestamps = false
level.save
Account.record_timestamps = true
```

You can make it look prettier by creating a wrapper method which will receive a block to execute without timestamps.